# Laravel 5.3 Eloquent transactions and foreign key restrictions

Tags: postgresql, laravel, transactions, eloquent, foreign-keys

Am working on bigger project where we have multiple schemas in one Postgres DB. We have created foreign keys between schemas. Here is an example > 
We have company schema and user schema. Company schema has company_users table which have foreign key restriction on user.users table

```
CREATE TABLE company.company_user
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  company_id integer NOT NULL,
  user_id integer NOT NULL,
  created_at timestamp(0) without time zone,
  updated_at timestamp(0) without time zone,
  deleted_at timestamp(0) without time zone,
  CONSTRAINT company_user_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT company_user_company_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (company_id)
      REFERENCES company.companies (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT company_user_user_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
      REFERENCES "user".users (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Following queries run in Postgres without issue

```
BEGIN;
insert into "db"."user"."users" (id,"surname", "firstname", "email", "position", "language_id", "is_super_admin", "updated_at", "created_at") values (156,'Mueller', 'Julianne', 'julianne.mueller1@example.org', 'Nuclear Power Reactor Operator', 41, false, '2017-01-13 12:35:10', '2017-01-13 12:35:10') returning "id";
insert into "db"."company"."company_user" ("company_id", "user_id", "updated_at", "created_at") values (4445, 156, '2017-01-13 12:35:10', '2017-01-13 12:35:10') returning "id";
COMMIT;
```

However if i perform same queries via Eloquent in Laravel

```
\DB::beginTransaction();
$user = new User(["surname" => 'Mueller',
                  "firstname" => 'Julianne',
                  "email" => 'julianne.mueller1@example.org',
                  "position" => 'Nuclear Power Reactor Operator',
                  "language_id" => 41,
                  "is_super_admin" => false]
);
if (!$user->save()) {
    \DB::rollBack();
    return false;
}
\Log::error($user->id);
$company_user = new CompanyUser([
    "company_id" => 4445,
    "user_id" => $user->id
]);
if (!$company_user->save()) {
    \DB::rollBack();
    return false;
}
\DB::commit();
```

is throwing folloing error (it seems that it cannot find id of user in the table)

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23503]: Foreign key violation: 7 ERROR: insert or update on table "company_user" violates foreign key constraint "company_user_user_id_foreign"
```

Would anyone can say why this is not working? \Log::error($user->id) is printing id of inserted user. I tried to print out queries from Laravel with DB listener, all queries are executed in correct order, but am still getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so we found a solution. It seems that we need to start transaction for each of schemas separately + each foreign key that are referencing different schema than their own should be created as deferred.

Comment: Wow! This is a true gem! To add to your answer, and to clarify for others who may have the same issue, when Lukas says `each foreign key that are referencing different schema than their own should be created as deferred`, he is referring to the foreign key as defined on the referencing table. In most IDEs (such as Navicat), this option is on the `Foreign Keys` tab and the options that solve this problem are labeled as `Deferrable: DEFERRABLE` and `Deferred: INITIALLY DEFERRED`, instead of `INITIALLY IMMEDIATE`. Any idea if this can be set via built-in Laravel methods in the database migration?

Comment: To follow-up regarding my previous comment, Laravel seems not to have built-in support for deferrable constraints in the Migration context. One can add them using a raw statement within a migration, however, e.g.: `DB::statement('ALTER TABLE foo.bar ADD CONSTRAINT foo_bar_user_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES laravel.users(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;');` Note also that one cannot update an existing constraint to include `DEFERRABLE`; it is necessary to drop the old constraint first, then add the new one, and the dropping and adding must occur in separate migrations.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure `CompanyUser` has `$fillable`:

```
$fillable = ['user_id', 'company_id'];
```

Also, make sure there is a user with this ID is already in `users` table. Maybe you'll need to get rid of transaction.

Comment: Hey Alexey. Its a bit more complicated than that. Yes companyUser has both of them set as fillable, there is small piece of code there where am calling \Log::error($user->id) after user was saved and In log am getting the id so it seems that Eloquent is saving that row. Even if i try to listen for database queries all of them are running in correct order eg first inserting to users table then inserting to company users but still same error

Comment: Did you try to do that without transaction?

Comment: Without transaction it is working, however I need transactions for these types of queries. This is just example. But I will be calling different APIs and when one of them fails I need to revert all changes back.

Comment: Well if user wasn't created yet, it's normal query fails. How about removing constraint, but keeping the key so relationships could still work?