# Laravel inserting parent child fails inside transaction

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, transactions, foreign-keys

I am trying to perform 2 inserts, in 2 tables table are constrained via a foreign key. These 2 operations **MUST** be performed inside a transaction to prevent eventual failures. (In reality I need to perform more inserts on more tables so transactions are important; but the 2 tables in this example are enough to replicate the problem)

The database driver is **pgsql**

**SomeRepo.php** (Tried it with the the transaction closure variant as well)

```
        DB::beginTransaction();
        try {
            $parentData = [
                'name' => 'Parent name'
            ];
            $parent = new Parent($parentData);
            $parent->save();

            $childData = [
                // Tried it with and without setting "parent_id" here
                'parent_id' => $parent->id,
                'name' => 'Child name'
            ];
            $child = new Child($childData);
            $parent->children()->save($child);
            DB::commit();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            DB::rollback();
        }
```

**Parent.php**

```
    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Child::class);
    }
```

**Child.php**

```
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'parent_id'
    ];
```

Execution fails when trying to insert the child row, with the return parent id.

```
insert or update on table "child" violates foreign key constraint "child_parent_id_foreign"
```

**EDIT**
Child table SQL:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "public"."child";
CREATE TABLE "public"."child" (
  "id" int4 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('child_id_seq'::regclass),
  "parent_id" int4 NOT NULL,
  "is_read" bool NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
  "created_at" timestamp(0) DEFAULT now(),
  "updated_at" timestamp(0),
  "deleted_at" timestamp(0)
)
;
ALTER TABLE "public"."child" OWNER TO "my_user";

-- ----------------------------
-- Primary Key structure for table child
-- ----------------------------
ALTER TABLE "public"."child" ADD CONSTRAINT "child_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id");

-- ----------------------------
-- Foreign Keys structure for table child
-- ----------------------------
ALTER TABLE "public"."child" ADD CONSTRAINT "child_parent_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("parent_id") REFERENCES "public"."parent" ("id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
```

Comment: Could you please show us the structure of the database?

Comment: I think this the case of chicken-and-egg problem of inserting into tables with circular references in postgreSql

Comment: try dumping $parent->id right after the ->save()... make sure the data is actually there.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41715578/2693543, please read the comment on this question

Comment: plus you can check this out as well https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/deferring-database-constraints

Answer (score 0):

To save data in related table use this

```
Parent::create(['name'=>'parent name']); //save in parent table
$lastId = Parent::query()->max('id'); //get last inserted row id

$parent = App\Parent::find($lastId);

$child = $parent->children()->create([
    'message' => 'A new comment.',
]);
```

You can also use `createMany` method

```
$parent = App\Parent::find($lastId);

$parent->children()->createMany([
    [
        'message' => 'A new comment.',
    ],
    [
        'message' => 'Another new comment.',
    ],
]);
```

Comment: Why are you getting the parent model by using last id? According to the eloquent documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent) `Parent::create()` returns the created model so there is no need for those two extra lines (which are dangerous because of using last id which isn't 100% safe).

Comment: Querying for the max id is not required. Tried your code and it gives the same exact foreign key error. Did you try to run it against a PostgreSQL database?

Answer (score 0):

Try it with this code by using `create` and `createMany` on the relation of the Parent model:

```
// Create the parent object.
$parent = Parent::create([
  'name' => 'Parent 1'
]);

// Insert one.
$child = $parent->children()->create([
    'name' => 'Child 1',
]);

// Insert many.
$parent->children()->createMany([
    [
        'name' => 'Child 2',
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Child 3',
    ],
]);
```

Comment: Without transactions this will definitely work. But as you can see in the original question I need to do everything in a transaction, with a PostgreSQL database.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
try {
     DB::beginTransaction();
       $parent = Parent::create([
     'name' => 'Parent name'
     ]);
     $parent->children()->create([
       'parent_id' => $parent->id,
       'name' => 'Child name'
     ]);
     DB::commit();
 } catch (Exception $e) {
     DB::rollback();
 }
```

Comment: How is this code any different from the one in the original question?

Answer (score 0):

alter the foreign key-- run this sql on the database

```
alter table child drop constraint child_parent_id;

alter table child add foreign key (parent_id) references parent(id) deferrable initially deferred;
```

This will allow you to create the child or parent in either order and the constraint will not be validated until the commit. It should not be necessary in this case-- however, It does depend on how your IDs are generated.

Comment: I've tried it but I still get the same error: `insert or update on table "child" violates foreign key constraint "child_parent_id_fkey"↵DETAIL:  Key (parent_id)=(254) is not present in table "parent"`

My ids are generated from sequences with: `default value: nextval('parent_id_seq'::regclass)`

Comment: Check the foreign key on the child table. Perhaps it was created wrong. Can you paste in the DDL (SQL for creating) the foreign key constraint? It's either that, or the data inserted is NOT correct.. Meaning, the child table insert is not inserting the parent key you just created. That actually makes more sense because normally you don't have to do deferred constraints if you're creating this data in the right order, and according to your source, you are.

Comment: I updated the question with the SQL used to create the child table. Also I have logged the id of the created parent, and it matches the parent_id field present in the INSERT performed on the child table that return the FK error.

Answer (score -1):

children function needs a middle table change it to :

```
 public function children()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Child::class);
}
```

and don't do this `$parent->children()->save($child);`.

or if you want to go that way make `child_parent` table, with 2 fields `child_id` and `parent_id`.

Comment: My scenario uses one-to-many.I don't want to implement a many-to-many relationship if there's no use for it.

Answer (score -1):

I dont test, but i think the DB method `DB::table('---')->insert()` can work for your situation